# ProcessBuilder start java program: IOException. Faild to start process. Reason: Cannot run program CreateProcess error=2

Tags: java

I have a simple class like this:

```
public class Dog  {
  public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println("DOG");
    }
}
```

It is complied into `Dog.class` which is located inside `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Test\classes`. I try to run it using ProcessBuilder:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pathName = "-cp \"C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.5\\webapps\\Test\\classes" + "\" " + "Dog";
        runCode(pathName); 
    }
```

```
public static void runCode(String name)  {
           System.out.println(name);  //-cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Test\classes" Dog

           ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("java " + name);
           processBuilder.redirectError(new File(Paths.get("C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.5\\webapps\\JavaStudyRooms\\output.txt").toString()));
           processBuilder.redirectInput();

       try {
           final Process process = processBuilder.start();
           try {
               final int exitStatus = process.waitFor();
               if(exitStatus==0){
                   System.out.println("External class  Started Successfully.");
                   System.exit(0); //or whatever suits
               }else{
                   System.out.println("There was an error starting external class. Perhaps path issues. Use exit code "+exitStatus+" for details.");
                   System.out.println("Check also output file for additional details.");
                   System.exit(1);//whatever
               }
           } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
               System.out.println("InterruptedException: "+ex.getMessage());
           }
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           System.out.println("IOException. Faild to start process. Reason: "+ex.getMessage());
       }
       System.out.println("Process Terminated.");
       System.exit(0);

   }
```

gives error:

```
-cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Test\classes" Dog
IOException. Faild to start process. Reason: Cannot run program "java -cp "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Test\classes" Dog": CreateProcess error=2, Cannot find the file
Process Terminated.
```

Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProcessBuilder does not take an entire command line.  It takes arguments.

Your current code is looking for a program whose base name is 90 characters long, for example `java -cp … Dog.exe`.

You need to pass an array of arguments:

```
// Note the use of a String array, not a single String

public static void runCode(String... javaArgs) {

    List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();
    args.add("java");
    Collections.addAll(args, javaArgs);

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);
```

This can be invoked as:

```
runCode(
    "-cp",
    "C:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 8.5\\webapps\\Test\\classes",
    "Dog");
```

Also, don’t just print out an exception’s message.  The message by itself is rarely useful.  You usually want to print the entire stack trace, so you’ll have all the information and you’ll know exactly where the problem occurred:

```
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: It still gives `Cannot run program "-cp": CreateProcess error=2 File not found` error ; (

Comment: ok, nevermind , it just should have been `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(args);` instead of `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(javaArgs);`.

Comment: @parsecer Right you are.  Fixed.